# calculation of 90 percentile and replacement of it by median by groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lapply

Here part of data.

```
mydat=structure(list(code = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 
222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 
222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 
222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 
222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L), 
    item = c(234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 
    234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 
    234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 
    234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 
    234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 333L, 
    333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 
    333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 
    333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 
    333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 
    333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L), return = c(25L, 25L, 
    21L, 37L, 23L, 27L, 19L, 7L, 16L, 12L, 33L, 24L, 6L, 14L, 
    4L, 25L, 90L, 27L, 3L, 16L, 7L, 1L, 13L, 11L, 36L, 5L, 6L, 
    14L, 11L, 41L, 11L, 6L, 4L, 11L, 3L, 6L, 21L, 41L, 28L, 30L, 
    92L, 4L, 1L, 83L, 3L, 16L, 4L, 25L, 25L, 21L, 37L, 23L, 27L, 
    19L, 7L, 16L, 12L, 33L, 24L, 6L, 14L, 4L, 25L, 90L, 27L, 
    3L, 16L, 7L, 1L, 13L, 11L, 36L, 5L, 6L, 14L, 11L, 41L, 11L, 
    6L, 4L, 11L, 3L, 6L, 21L, 41L, 28L, 30L, 92L, 4L, 1L, 83L, 
    3L, 16L, 4L), action = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("code", 
"item", "return", "action"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-94L))
```

I have 2 group vars code+item. Here two groups:

```
123 234
222 333
```

Also i have action column. It can have only two values(category) zero(0) or one(1).

i need calculate `90 percentile` by zero category of action of return column, which go before one category of action.
Then i need calculate the `median` by zero category of action of return column, which go before one category of action. (After one we don't touch zeros)

## These statistics must be calculate by 14 zeros preceding the  one category of action

Then i have to find values that more 90  percentile which was calculated above, then such values must be replce by the median which was calculated.

After one category of action go zero category again for return column. For it i too have to find value that more  90  percentile which was calculeted above, then such value must be replaced by the median which was calculeted above(when calculate for 14 zeros).

Note the `calculation` is done by 14 zeros preceding the  one category of action
but `replacing` by median is done for all `zero category` of action
and performing for each groups `code+item`

The result can be in output column.

to be more clear here desired output.

for `123+234` group
the 90 perc=39,5
median=12

for `222+333`
the 90 perc=39,5
median=12

```
 code item return action output
1   123  234     25      0     25
2   123  234     25      0     25
3   123  234     21      0     21
4   123  234     37      0     16
5   123  234     23      0     23
6   123  234     27      0     27
7   123  234     19      0     19
8   123  234      7      0      7
9   123  234     16      0     16
10  123  234     12      0     12
11  123  234     33      0     33
12  123  234     24      0     24
13  123  234      6      0      6
14  123  234     14      0     14
15  123  234      4      0      4
16  123  234     25      0     25
17  123  234     90      0     **12**
18  123  234     27      0     27
19  123  234      3      0      3
20  123  234     16      0     16
21  123  234      7      0      7
22  123  234      1      0      1
23  123  234     13      0     13
24  123  234     11      0     11
25  123  234     36      0     36
26  123  234      5      0      5
27  123  234      6      0      6
28  123  234     14      0     14
29  123  234     11      0     11
30  123  234     41      0     16
31  123  234     11      1     Na
32  123  234      6      1     Na
33  123  234      4      1     Na
34  123  234     11      1     Na
35  123  234      3      0      3
36  123  234      6      0      6
37  123  234     21      0     21
38  123  234     41      0     **12**
39  123  234     28      0     28
40  123  234     30      0     30
41  123  234     92      0     **12**
42  123  234      4      0      4
43  123  234      1      0      1
44  123  234     83      0     **12**
45  123  234      3      0      3
46  123  234     16      0     16
47  123  234      4      0      4
48  222  333     25      0     25
49  222  333     25      0     25
50  222  333     21      0     21
51  222  333     37      0     16
52  222  333     23      0     23
53  222  333     27      0     27
54  222  333     19      0     19
55  222  333      7      0      7
56  222  333     16      0     16
57  222  333     12      0     12
58  222  333     33      0     33
59  222  333     24      0     24
60  222  333      6      0      6
61  222  333     14      0     14
62  222  333      4      0      4
63  222  333     25      0     25
64  222  333     90      0     **12**
65  222  333     27      0     27
66  222  333      3      0      3
67  222  333     16      0     16
68  222  333      7      0      7
69  222  333      1      0      1
70  222  333     13      0     13
71  222  333     11      0     11
72  222  333     36      0     36
73  222  333      5      0      5
74  222  333      6      0      6
75  222  333     14      0     14
76  222  333     11      0     11
77  222  333     41      0     16
78  222  333     11      1     Na
79  222  333      6      1     Na
80  222  333      4      1     Na
81  222  333     11      1     Na
82  222  333      3      0      3
83  222  333      6      0      6
84  222  333     21      0     21
85  222  333     41      0     **12**
86  222  333     28      0     28
87  222  333     30      0     30
88  222  333     92      0     **12**
89  222  333      4      0      4
90  222  333      1      0      1
91  222  333     83      0     **12**
92  222  333      3      0      3
93  222  333     16      0     16
94  222  333      4      0      4
```

** i marked rows where value was replced by median.

Comment: Why does `output` for rows 41 and 77 show a value of 16 instead of 12? They should have replaced by the medain as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to

1. compute the 90% quantile and the median for the last 14 "zero action rows" (i.e., rows with `action == 0`) *before* the first row with `action == 1`, separately for each `code`, `item` group. (This implies that there is only one streak of `action == 1` values per group.
2. Copy the `return` values to the `output` for all rows with `action == 0`.
3. Replace the `output` value if it is larger than the 90% quantile by the median in *all* zero action rows before the first `action == 1` row in each group.

This can be solved by *updating in a non-equi join* with some preparations

```
library(data.table)
# mark the zero acton rows before the the action period
setDT(mydat)[, zero_before := cummax(action), by = .(code, item)]
# compute median and 90% quantile for that last 14 rows before each action period 
agg <- mydat[zero_before == 0, 
             quantile(tail(return, 14L), c(0.5, 0.9)) %>% 
               as.list()  %>% 
               set_names(c("med", "q90")) %>% 
               c(.(zero_before = 0)), by = .(code, item)]
agg

   code item med  q90 zero_before
1:  123  234  12 39.5           0
2:  222  333  12 39.5           0

# append output column
mydat[action == 0, output := as.double(return)][
  # replace output values greater q90 in an update non-equi join
  agg, on = .(code, item, action, return > q90), output := as.double(med)][
    # remove helper column
    , zero_before := NULL]
```

As `mydat` has 94 rows, we will show only the updated rows:

```
mydat[return != output]
```

> ```
>     code item return action output
>  1:  123  234     90      0     12
>  2:  123  234     41      0     12
>  3:  123  234     41      0     12
>  4:  123  234     92      0     12
>  5:  123  234     83      0     12
>  6:  222  333     90      0     12
>  7:  222  333     41      0     12
>  8:  222  333     41      0     12
>  9:  222  333     92      0     12
> 10:  222  333     83      0     12
> ```

Comment: i try to apply your code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074105/find-75-percentile-and-replacind-by-median-for-each-group-in-r and got the error. Can you help me please to understand why error occured?

Comment: The linked question is quite different. I posted an answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52076214/3817004).

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`:

```
 mydat%>%
  group_by(code,item)%>%
  mutate(output=ifelse(return>quantile(return,.9) & action==0,median(return),return))
```

Comment: thank you. May i ask you  to correct code? I wrote Note the calculation is done by 14 zeros preceding the one category of action but replacing by median is done for all zero category of action and performing for each groups code+item.   How to do that 90 percentile was calculate for 14 zeros preceding the one category of action + 7 zeros  after one category of action ,  but replacing by median is done for all zero category of action and performing for each groups code+item.

Comment: Please, check the results before posting an answer. Your answer returns an median of 14 while the OP expects an median of 12. The reason is that your answer computes the statistics for _all_ zero rows in each group while the OP has asked to consider *only the last 14 rows before the first row with* `action == 1`.