# calculation of 90 percentile and replacement it by median by groups in R using 14 and 7 days intervals

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

This post related with this my post
[calculation of 90 percentile and replacement of it by median by groups in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51929941/calculation-of-90-percentile-and-replacement-of-it-by-median-by-groups-in-r/51930017#51930017)

solution of jyjek helped me, but not fully.

```
 mydat%>%
  group_by(code,item)%>%
  mutate(output=ifelse(return>quantile(return,.9) & action==0,median(return),return))
```

There is condition for calculating the median and 90 percentile.

In OP , i wrote
 Note the calculation is done by 14 zeros preceding the one category of action but replacing by median is done for all zero category of action and performing for each groups code+item. How to do that 90 percentile was calculate for 14 zeros preceding the one category of action + 7 zeros after one category of action , but replacing by median must be done for all zero category of action and performing for each groups code+item

Here part of data.

```
mydat=structure(list(code = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 
222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 
222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 
222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 
222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L), 
    item = c(234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 
    234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 
    234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 
    234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 
    234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 333L, 
    333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 
    333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 
    333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 
    333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 
    333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L), return = c(25L, 25L, 
    21L, 37L, 23L, 27L, 19L, 7L, 16L, 12L, 33L, 24L, 6L, 14L, 
    4L, 25L, 90L, 27L, 3L, 16L, 7L, 1L, 13L, 11L, 36L, 5L, 6L, 
    14L, 11L, 41L, 11L, 6L, 4L, 11L, 3L, 6L, 21L, 41L, 28L, 30L, 
    92L, 4L, 1L, 83L, 3L, 16L, 4L, 25L, 25L, 21L, 37L, 23L, 27L, 
    19L, 7L, 16L, 12L, 33L, 24L, 6L, 14L, 4L, 25L, 90L, 27L, 
    3L, 16L, 7L, 1L, 13L, 11L, 36L, 5L, 6L, 14L, 11L, 41L, 11L, 
    6L, 4L, 11L, 3L, 6L, 21L, 41L, 28L, 30L, 92L, 4L, 1L, 83L, 
    3L, 16L, 4L), action = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("code", 
"item", "return", "action"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-94L))
```

I have 2 group vars code+item. Here two groups:

```
123 234
222 333
```

Also i have action column. It can have only two values(category) zero(0) or one(1).

i need calculate `90 percentile` by zero category of action of return column, which go before one category of action.
Then i need calculate the `median` by zero category of action of return column, which go before one category of action.

## How to do that 90 percentile was calculate for 14 zeros preceding the one category of action + 7 zeros after one category of action ,

Then i have to find values that more 90  percentile which was calculated above, then such values must be replce by the median which was calculated.
 but replacing by median must be done for all zero category of action and performing for each groups code+item

After one category of action go zero category again for return column. For it i too have to find value that more  90  percentile which was calculeted above, then such value must be replaced by the median which was calculeted above.

Note the `calculation` is done by 14 zeros preceding the  one category of action and 7 zeros after  one category of action.
but `replacing` by median is done for all `zero category` of action
and performing for each groups `code+item`

The result can be in output column.

to be more clear here desired output.

for `123+234` group
the 90 perc=41
median=14

for `222+333`
the 90 perc=41
median=14

```
 code item return action output
1   123  234     25      0     25
2   123  234     25      0     25
3   123  234     21      0     21
4   123  234     37      0     16
5   123  234     23      0     23
6   123  234     27      0     27
7   123  234     19      0     19
8   123  234      7      0      7
9   123  234     16      0     16
10  123  234     12      0     12
11  123  234     33      0     33
12  123  234     24      0     24
13  123  234      6      0      6
14  123  234     14      0     14
15  123  234      4      0      4
16  123  234     25      0     25
17  123  234     90      0     **14**
18  123  234     27      0     27
19  123  234      3      0      3
20  123  234     16      0     16
21  123  234      7      0      7
22  123  234      1      0      1
23  123  234     13      0     13
24  123  234     11      0     11
25  123  234     36      0     36
26  123  234      5      0      5
27  123  234      6      0      6
28  123  234     14      0     14
29  123  234     11      0     11
30  123  234     41      0     **14**
31  123  234     11      1     Na
32  123  234      6      1     Na
33  123  234      4      1     Na
34  123  234     11      1     Na
35  123  234      3      0      3
36  123  234      6      0      6
37  123  234     21      0     21
38  123  234     41      0     **14**
39  123  234     28      0     28
40  123  234     30      0     30
41  123  234     92      0     **14**
42  123  234      4      0      4
43  123  234      1      0      1
44  123  234     83      0     **14**
45  123  234      3      0      3
46  123  234     16      0     16
47  123  234      4      0      4
48  222  333     25      0     25
49  222  333     25      0     25
50  222  333     21      0     21
51  222  333     37      0     16
52  222  333     23      0     23
53  222  333     27      0     27
54  222  333     19      0     19
55  222  333      7      0      7
56  222  333     16      0     16
57  222  333     12      0     12
58  222  333     33      0     33
59  222  333     24      0     24
60  222  333      6      0      6
61  222  333     14      0     14
62  222  333      4      0      4
63  222  333     25      0     25
64  222  333     90      0     **14**
65  222  333     27      0     27
66  222  333      3      0      3
67  222  333     16      0     16
68  222  333      7      0      7
69  222  333      1      0      1
70  222  333     13      0     13
71  222  333     11      0     11
72  222  333     36      0     36
73  222  333      5      0      5
74  222  333      6      0      6
75  222  333     14      0     14
76  222  333     11      0     11
77  222  333     41      0     **14**
78  222  333     11      1     Na
79  222  333      6      1     Na
80  222  333      4      1     Na
81  222  333     11      1     Na
82  222  333      3      0      3
83  222  333      6      0      6
84  222  333     21      0     21
85  222  333     41      0     **14**
86  222  333     28      0     28
87  222  333     30      0     30
88  222  333     92      0     **14**
89  222  333      4      0      4
90  222  333      1      0      1
91  222  333     83      0     **14**
92  222  333      3      0      3
93  222  333     16      0     16
94  222  333      4      0      4
```

** i marked rows where value was replced by median.

The data for calculating percentile and median

```
return  action
90  0
27  0
3   0
16  0
7   0
1   0
13  0
11  0
36  0
5   0
6   0
14  0
11  0
41  0
11  1
6   1
4   1
11  1
3   0
6   0
21  0
41  0
28  0
30  0
92  0
```

14 zeros preceding the one category of action + 7 zeros after one category of action.

## Important edit

I have a suspicion of the reason for the error

here data

```
    item return code action
1  11202      6  137      0
2  11202      3  137      0
3  11202      5  137      0
4  11202      6  137      0
5  11202      4  137      0
6  11202     10  137      0
7  11202      1  137      0
8  11202     19  137      0
9  11202     16  137      0
10 11202      6  137      0
11 11202     11  137      0
12 11202     20  137      0
13 11202     19  137      0
14 11202     13  137      0
15 11202     14  137      0
16 11202     13  137      0
17 11202     21  137      0
18 11202     10  137      0
19 11202     16  137      0
20 11202      8  137      0
21 11202     15  137      0
22 11202      8  137      0
23 11202     25  137      0
24 11202     17  137      0
25 11202     21  137      0
26 11202     14  137      0
27 11202     15  137      0
28 11202      6  137      0
29 11202      5  137      0
30 11202     11  137      0
31 11202     11  137      0
32 11202      8  137      0
33 11202     12  137      1
38 11202     17  137      1
39 11202      9  137      0
40 11202      7  137      0
41 11202      4  137      0
```

as you can see before one category of action we have 14 zeros, but after one category we have only 4 zeros 
in this case we calculate 14 zeros before first one, then 4 zeros after one.
it can be this situation

## edit three

```
item    return  code    action  mask    output
11683   77  40  0   NA  77
11683   165 40  0   NA  68
11683   100 40  0   NA  100
11683   84  40  0   NA  84
11683   80  40  0   NA  80
11683   52  40  0   NA  52
11683   1   40  0   NA  1
11683   106 40  0   NA  106
11683   70  40  0   NA  70
11683   88  40  0   NA  88
11683   49  40  0   NA  49
11683   107 40  0   NA  107
11683   25  40  0   NA  25
11683   18  40  0   NA  18
11683   77  40  0   NA  77
11683   70  40  0   NA  70
11683   54  40  0   NA  54
11683   74  40  0   NA  74
11683   115 40  0   NA  68
11683   45  40  0   NA  45
11683   22  40  0   NA  22
11683   95  40  0   NA  95
11683   73  40  0   NA  73
11683   69  40  0   NA  69
11683   70  40  0   1   70
11683   71  40  0   1   71
11683   37  40  0   1   37
11683   20  40  0   1   20
11683   49  40  0   1   49
11683   102 40  0   1   102
11683   113 40  0   1   68
11683   110 40  0   1   110
11683   117 40  0   1   68
11683   42  40  0   1   42
11683   7   40  1   NA  7
11683   117 40  1   NA  117
11683   117 40  1   NA  117
11683   132 40  1   NA  132
11683   108 40  1   NA  108
11683   68  40  1   NA  68
11683   51  40  1   NA  51
11683   8   40  1   NA  8
11683   63  40  1   NA  63
11683   88  40  1   NA  88
11683   90  40  1   NA  90
11683   92  40  1   NA  92
11683   80  40  1   NA  80
11683   54  40  1   NA  54
11683   5   40  1   NA  5
11683   139 40  1   NA  139
11683   122 40  1   NA  122
11683   68  40  1   NA  68
11683   43  40  1   NA  43
11683   29  40  1   NA  29
11683   21  40  1   NA  21
11683   12  40  1   NA  12
11683   0   40  1   NA  0
11683   43  40  0   1   43
11683   33  40  0   1   33
11683   53  40  0   1   53
11683   101 40  0   1   101
11683   61  40  0   1   61
11683   13  40  0   1   13
11683   51  40  0   1   51
11683   83  40  0   NA  83
11683   30  40  0   NA  30
11683   59  40  0   NA  59
11683   37  40  0   NA  37
11683   20  40  0   NA  20
11683   9   40  0   NA  9
11683   125 40  0   NA  68
11683   33  40  0   NA  33
```

median and percentile calculate by these data 10 before, 7 after

```
70
71
37
20
49
102
113
110
117
42
43
33
53
101
61
13
51
```

median is 53, but all that more than 90 percentile replaced on 68, cause 68 is median for all obs.

Comment: Please make the question self-contained by adding sample data with expected output.

Comment: @RalfStubner, i edited post., Please check

Comment: Why are the values of 41 in lines 30 and 77 not replaced?

Comment: @RalfStubner, i edited post. it wasn't replaced by my inattention.

Comment: I have understood that the 90% quantile is to be computed based on the 14 zero action rows preceeding the action phase and the 7 zero action rows succeeding the action phase. Is the median to be calculated on the basis or from _all_ zero action rows in each group?

Comment: @Uwe, the median is calculated for  each group by 14 zeros category of action before one and then 7 zeros category after one.

Comment: @Uwe, i edited post, can you check it?

Comment: @D.Joe I have posted an answer including your second use case.

Comment: @D.Joe May I kindly suggest to [edit] your question and clarify the following issues, please. 1) You are writing about _"to find values that more 90 percentile"_ which implies a _greater_ relation but the expected result had also values replaced where return _equals_ the 90% quantile. 2) In your first edit you are writing _"before one category of action we have 14 zeros, but after one category we have only 4 zeros"_. The posted dataset has only 3 zeros after the streak of ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your question:

- Per `code` and `item` you have a range of rows with `action == 1`.
- You want to take 10 rows before that range ad 7 rows after that range.
- For these 17 rows, where `action == 0` holds, you get the 90% quantile.
- Than you compare *all* rows with `action == 0` to this quantile. If the value is larger or equal, you replace it with the mean of *all* rows *independent of* `action`.

If this is correct, then you can use the following:

```
library(dplyr)
get_mask <- function(action) {
  ones <- which(action == 1)
  end_before <- max(0, min(ones) - 1)
  start_before <- max(0, end_before - 9)
  start_after <- min(length(action), max(ones) + 1)
  end_after <- min(length(action), start_after + 6)
  indices <- c(seq.int(from = start_before, to = end_before), 
               seq.int(from = start_after, to = end_after))
  result <- rep(NA_real_, length(action))
  result[indices] <- 1
  result
}


mydat %>%
  group_by(code,item) %>%
  mutate(mask = get_mask(action)) %>%
  mutate(output = ifelse(return>=quantile(mask * return, .9, na.rm = TRUE) & action==0,
                         median(return), return))
```

The main idea is to introduce a `mask` column which determines whether or not a particular row is to be included in the quantile calculation.

Comment: Tell me please. Why when i use ths script not in test data, but for all data, i get error Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `mask` must be length 61 (the group size) or one, not 62. How can i fix it. Thank you

Comment: I edited post with suspicion of the reason for the error. Is it possible be.

Comment: @D.Joe Please see the updated code. Besides fixing an "off by one error", I also check if there are fewer than 10/7 zeros before/after the block of ones.

Comment: In your code, everything is fine, except for one thing. it must find 10 zeros preceding  one category of action, and 7 zeros after one category, and then by these 17 zeros it must calculate the median. Checking for real data, I saw that it calculates the median for all observations. I edited post , please see it with example of the real data.

Comment: @D.Joe That's what I wrote in my forth bullet point. the mean is calculated for all elements. Otherwise the man is not 14 in your example data! However, the fix is easy: just use `mean(mask * return, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the `action` column of each `code`, `item` group consists of a sequence of zeros followed by one more consecutive ones and completed by another sequence of zeros, finally. There is only one streak of ones in each group.

The OP wants to

1. compute the 90% quantile and the median for the *last* 14 "zero action rows" (i.e., rows with `action == 0`) *before* the first row with `action == 1` *and* for the *first* 7 rows *after* the last row with `action == 1`, separately for each `code`, `item` group.
2. From OP's edit: In case there are less than 14 zeros before or less than 7 zeros after the streak of ones in `action` the statistics are to be computed for the available zero action rows.
3. Copy the `return` values to the `output` for all rows with `action == 0`.
4. Replace the `output` value if it is greater *or equal* than the 90% quantile by the median in *all* zero action rows before the first `action == 1` row in each group.
   Note that the OP is talking about *to find values that more 90 percentile* which implies a *greater* relation but the expected result had also values replaced where return *equals* the 90% quantile.

This can be solved by *updating in a non-equi join* with some preparations. The crucial part is to identify the zero action rows before the streak of one and the zero action rows after. This is done by `cummax(action)` for the zero action rows before the first `action == 1` row and by a double reversed `rev(cummax(rev(action)))` for the zero action rows after the first `action == 1` which runs the rows from backwards.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
# mark the zero action rows before and after the the action period
setDT(mydat)[
  , c("zero_before", "zero_after") := .(cummax(action), rev(cummax(rev(action)))), 
  by = .(code, item)]
# compute median and 90% quantile for the last 14 rows before and 
# the first 7 rows after each action period 
agg <- mydat[, quantile(c(tail(return[zero_before == 0], 14L), 
                          head(return[zero_after == 0], 7L)), c(0.5, 0.9)) %>% 
               as.list()  %>% 
               set_names(c("med", "q90")) %>% 
               c(.(action = 0)), by = .(code, item)]
agg
```

> ```
> agg
>    code item med q90 action
> 1:  123  234  14  41      0
> 2:  222  333  14  41      0
> ```

Now we can copy `return` to `output` for all zero action rows and replace `output` values greater than the 90% quantile in an update non-equi join:

```
mydat[action == 0, output := as.double(return)][
  # replace output values greater q90 in an update non-equi join
  agg, on = .(code, item, action, return > q90), output := as.double(med)][
    # remove helper column
    , c("zero_before", "zero_after") := NULL]
```

As `mydat` consists of 94 rows we will only show the rows where `return` differs from `output`:

> ```
>     code item return action output
>  1:  123  234     90      0     14
>  2:  123  234     41      0     14
>  3:  123  234     41      0     14
>  4:  123  234     92      0     14
>  5:  123  234     83      0     14
>  6:  222  333     90      0     14
>  7:  222  333     41      0     14
>  8:  222  333     41      0     14
>  9:  222  333     92      0     14
> 10:  222  333     83      0     14
> ```

#### EDIT: Second use case

The OP has provided a second use case:

```
mydat <-
structure(list(item = c(11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L
), return = c(6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 10L, 1L, 19L, 16L, 6L, 11L, 
20L, 19L, 13L, 14L, 13L, 21L, 10L, 16L, 8L, 15L, 8L, 25L, 17L, 
21L, 14L, 15L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 12L, 17L, 9L, 7L, 4L), code = c(137L, 
137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 
137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 
137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 
137L, 137L, 137L), action = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-37L), class = "data.frame")
```

where there are only 3 zero action rows after the streak of ones.
For this use case we get

```
agg
```

> ```
>    code  item med  q90 action
> 1:  137 11202  11 18.6      0
> ```

and

```
mydat[return != output]
```

> ```
>     item return code action output
> 1: 11202     19  137      0     11
> 2: 11202     20  137      0     11
> 3: 11202     19  137      0     11
> 4: 11202     21  137      0     11
> 5: 11202     25  137      0     11
> 6: 11202     21  137      0     11
> ```